# Adding OpenWeatherMap WMS layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, wms, openweathermap-api

I would like to add in QGIS real time weather data.

I found this [link](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783984985/5/ch05lvl1sec98/adding-real-time-weather-data-from-openweathermap) and this [link](https://www.gislounge.com/adding-real-time-weather-data-from-openweathermap-qgis-python-programming-cookbook/) and I tried to follow the example, but without any success.

I've added a WMS weather data layer for precipitation to the QGIS map, as follows:

First, the parameters for the service:

```
service = 'crs=EPSG:900913&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=precipitation&styles=&url=http://wms.openweathermap.org/service'
```

Next, create the raster layer, specifying WMS as the type:

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(service, "precip", "wms")
```

Finally, add the precipitation layer to the map:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([rlayer])
```

the example didn't show any error in the code and no data was added to the weather layer either, I'm not sure why?

Comment: According to http://openweathermap.org/api you need an API key to access their service.

Comment: @ AndreJ  I have API key but hot to add correct in services ?

Comment: it is documented here http://openweathermap.org/api/weathermaps

Comment: `dpiMode=7&` is certainly wrong possibly 72 is meant, You are using CRS as a parameter so check you are using version 1.3.0.   Can you actually post the WMS GetMap request that is made to the server.

Comment: @Mapperz but icant use this docs to add in QGIS,@nmtoken i test your proposal but don't work again