# Importing OpenWeatherMap to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openweathermap-api

I have a problem importing OpenWeatherMap to QGIS. I am new to this type of importing. I have searched old topics, but it seems that things have changed now.

Basically, I have a map in QGIS, and I want to overlay the existing map with a real-time weather data.

Comment: What did u try so far ?

Comment: service = 'crs=EPSG:900913&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=precipitation&styles=&url=http://wms.openweathermap.org/service'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(service, "precip", "wms")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([rlayer])

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/278892/49538